# Three.js Embedded HTML: How do I make the Links in the iFrame clickable?

Tags: three.js

I am looking at the example "Embedded HTML - Displays an interactive webpage within a Three.js scene. Based on the work of Jerome Etienne: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/" on http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html

(All example are here: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/).

Now the question is, how do I make the links within the iFrame actually clickable?

Any help is appreciated.